# php echo changing the spacing of elements

Tags: php, html, css, echo, letter-spacing

When I do this

```html
<li class="language">
   <a href="felt.php?lang=en">en</a>
   <a href="felt.php?lang=jp">jp</a>
   <a href="felt.php?lang=ru">ru</a>
</li>
```

it gives me space between the a tags, with space

[image: with space]

but when I do

```
  echo '<li class="language">';
  echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=en">en</a>';
  echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=jp">jp</a>';
  echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=ru">ru</a>';
  echo '</li>';
```

It takes away the spaces. why is this? I have not applied any css...

Comment: D.R.Y.: https://3v4l.org/1BWHX

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are writing it wrong, you should write it like:

```php
echo '<li class="language">
    <a href="felt.php?lang=en">en</a>
    <a href="felt.php?lang=jp">jp</a>
    <a href="felt.php?lang=ru">ru</a>
    </li>';
```

In your case, the `echo` will consider it as inline so it will delete the space, if you want to keep your structure you can always add it like:

```php
echo '<li class="language">';
echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=en">en</a>';
echo ' ';
echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=jp">jp</a>';
echo ' ';
echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=ru">ru</a>';
echo '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In php echo doesn't add any space or new line in the end of output.
This code

```
  echo '<li class="language">';
  echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=en">en</a>';
  echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=jp">jp</a>';
  echo '<a href="felt.php?lang=ru">ru</a>';
  echo '</li>';
```

will be translated as if you write html in one line.

```
<li class="language"><a href="felt.php?lang=en">en</a><a href="felt.php?lang=jp">jp</a><a href="felt.php?lang=ru">ru</a></li>
```

And if you care how browsers treat whitespace Mozilla have a good article -
[How whitespace is handled by HTML, CSS, and in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#spaces_in_between_inline_and_inline-block_elements)